# Problema al Cambiar el Estado de un atributo de una base de datos en java

Tags: java

Tengo un `checkbox` en la primera columna de mi `jtable` para seleccionar las filas de los registros que quiero cambiar de estado osea de `true` a `false` y viceversa  pero al momento de hacer click en un checkbox y después volver a quitar la bandera azul del check para quitar el seleccionado el método igual me lo toma entonces cree este método pero igual no me funciona

```
private void datalistadoMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

         int fila =datalistado.getSelectedRow();
         TableModel model = datalistado.getModel();
            if (fila != y){
              y = fila;
              rep=0;
              rep++;
            }else{
              rep++;
            }
            if(rep%2==0){   
                  listaRIF.removeLast();
                  listaEstado.removeLast();
            }else{
                  listaRIF.add((String)datalistado.getValueAt(fila,1));
                  listaEstado.add((Boolean)datalistado.getValueAt(fila,9));
           }  
    }             `
```